# iOS Memory Leak using coreplot

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, memory-leaks, core-plot

I am getting a memory warning after setting up a bar chart, hitting the home button and returning to the chart (it recreates after starting back up).  I am trying to find the memory leak in Instruments but I'm not sure what I'm looking for, below is a screenshot from Instruments.

[image]

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: I don't see any Core Plot objects in that report. Have you run the static analyzer on your app? It can often find memory management problems that lead to leads.